# Some usage of 'must'

Tags: meaning

I'm wondering which meaning this sentence has:

> She must hate me.

1. I need/want her to hate me
2. I assume she hates me

or both are possible depending on the context?

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible, depending on context - in particular, tense.

Future tense.  "She must hate me" = "She will come to hate me."

1. It is imperative that she hates me, so I will work to make sure that this happens in the future.

Present tense:  "She must hate me" = "It must be true that she hates me."

2. Given what we know to be true, we can conclude that she does, now, hate me.